# Create Dataframe from output of Function

Tags: scala, function, loops, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The scala code below is using a function to count the number of days between a user's input of a `start` and `end` date. It then iterates/reads through the aws s3 files that are within that time range.

```
def getS3Data(s3Loc: String): DataFrame = {
println(s"Reading Avro from ${s3Loc}")
val cosimDf = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
  .load(s3Loc)
  cosimDf
}

val daysCount = Days.daysBetween(start,end).getDays()
(0 until daysCount).map(start.plusDays(_)).foreach{x => {var myDir ="s3://AWS.Bucket/parsed/" + x.toString("yyyyMMdd") +"/"

val myDf = getS3Data(myDir)
}}
```

I am having trouble creating a dataframe that is a collection of all of the files that the above function iterated through. I think possibly using `.collect` or applying the output to a temptable may work, but cannot seem to figure out how.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You may create dataframes in the loop

If you know the type of the records stored in avro files, then you just replace `foreach` with `foldLeft` and set initial value being empty dataframe of given type

```
case class YourS3RowCaseClass(...) // replace with your type

val daysCount = Days.daysBetween(start,end).getDays()
val finalDf = (0 until daysCount).map(start.plusDays(_))
  .foldLeft(spark.createDataFrame(Seq.empty[YourS3RowCaseClass])){
    case (df, x) => 
        var myDir ="s3://AWS.Bucket/parsed/" + x.toString("yyyyMMdd") +"/"
        val myDf = getS3Data(myDir)
        df.union(myDf)
  }
```

If you have to infer the type from the dataframe, it may be a bit trickier then

Comment: Thank you for the response and great point on the `foldleft` option. I realize I can create and access the data within the loop, my issue is accessing it outside of the loop.

Comment: Unless, I'm missing something, you're looking for creating dataframe that will contain all the rows from all the dataframes you read via mapping. In the code provided above, `finalDf` will have a joined (unioned, to be more specific) DFs at the end of the loop.  So, in every step, it'll read the dataframe, union it with previously read ones, and return to be the source for the next iteration. If that's not what you're looking for, let me know